# How to split a string on spaces in Clean?

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

I'm a newbie with functional programming and Clean. I want to split a string on whitespace, like the `words` function in Haskell.

```
words :: String -> [String]
input: "my separated list " 
output: ["my","separated","list"]
```

This is the definition in Haskell:

```
words :: String -> [String]
words s =  case dropWhile {-partain:Char.-}isSpace s of
             "" -> []
             s' -> w : words s''
                where (w, s'') =
                    break {-partain:Char.-}isSpace s'
```

But Clean doesn't have `break`, and I dont know what it means, and how to implement it in Clean:

```
s' -> w : words s''
where (w, s'')
```

Comment: Well, if you implement the break function in CLEAN then you'd be able to finish this function, yes? Then go look at the definition for break for haskell. If I remember correctly it doesn't use many fancy tricks and is pretty simple to understand

Comment: looks like someone had a similar question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357128/split-string-to-a-list-of-strings-in-clean

Comment: if i would implement break, then remains the highlighted syntactical construction which i dont know how working

Comment: the another post i dont think it's working because in the spliton' you cannot handling String as a list semantically, generates compilation error

Comment: Haskell's break function is very similar to Clean's span function. But  span is working on list and makes list of lists(of chars), after that i cannot merge the lists in another step, or i dont know how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [StdEnvApi document](http://www.mbsd.cs.ru.nl/publications/papers/2010/CleanStdEnvAPI.pdf) advises you should convert the String to a list to use the StdList API functions (section 6, page 20).
This results in something like this:

```
splitString :: String -> [String]
splitString x = [foldr (+++) "" i\\i<- splitString` (fromString x)]
    where
        splitString` :: [String] -> [[String]]
        splitString` x = let (p, n) = span ((<>) " ") x in
            if (isEmpty n) [p] [p:splitString` (tl n)]
```